# Create .url files when drag and drop from browser instead of .desktop

Tags: .desktop, drag-and-drop, url

I used to drag-and-drop links from the browser in Windows to a folder to save them. That created files with extension .url, and the content is like:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://askubuntu.com/
```

When I drag-and-drop the link from browser in Ubuntu to a directory it creates a .desktop file instead of .url file and the structure is like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Icon=text-html
Name=https://askubuntu.com/
Type=Link
URL[$e]=https://askubuntu.com/
```

I was able to find a way to open up my .url files in Ubuntu when double-clicking them (found the solution here for that: https://devio.wordpress.com/2020/03/22/opening-url-files-in-ubuntu/), but I couldn't find a solution how I could continue saving the links as .url files instead of .desktop files in Ubuntu.
I found the same question here, and wanted to write this as a comment to that, but I don't have enough points to comment yet:
[How to save a website link as a .url / .webloc file instead of .desktop [NextCloud LinkEditor compatibility]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232362/how-to-save-a-website-link-as-a-url-webloc-file-instead-of-desktop-nextclo?newreg=28e03fe6095d482885cda98d84e387ca)

It would be really useful if I could drag-and-drop web links to save them as .url files so it can be cross-platform compatible.

Thanks

Comment: I don't even get a .desktop file with Chrome. If I drag the selected text in the address bar I get a .html file. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I was using Chrome, but I was dragging the url from the browser to the desktop, not to the address bar. Then I organized those files into certain folders. I have them in Dropbox so I can access them from anywhere. Or dragged from browser directly to those folders.